# Add Control to User Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a user control with WPF which is supposed to take in a list of controls as its content.
I succeeded in creating such a user control, but have run into the issue that I cannot name any of the sub-controls I added.

Here's the code for the user control:

```cs
public static DependencyProperty InnerContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TaskListItems", 
typeof(UIElement), typeof(TaskList));

public UIElement TaskListItems {
    get { return (UIElement)GetValue(InnerContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value); }
}
```

And the XAML (relevant part):

```cs
<ScrollViewer>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding TaskListItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TaskList}}}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The implementation then looks like so:

```cs
<uc:TaskList Grid.Column="0" HeaderText="Daily Task List" FooterText="Completed: 10">
    <uc:TaskList.TaskListItems>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Some Button"/>
            <Button Content="Some Button 2"/>
         </StackPanel>
    </uc:TaskList.TaskListItems>
</uc:TaskList>
```

So when I add a control to my user control such as a button for example, everything works fine, except I cannot give the button a name and I get the error:

`Cannot set Name attribute value 'test' on element 'Button'. 'Button' is under the scope of element 'TaskList', which already had a name registered when it was defined in another scope`

So my question is, is there a way to functionally do the same thing here, but also letting me give my controls names?

Edit for more information:

[image: task list design]

[image: task list item design]

What I'm going for is a user control that can take in a list of other user controls I created.
Those "list item" controls have four buttons each (the text bit is also a button):

The text button just opens a window with info about the selected task.
The check mark button is supposed to create an event to request the tasks completion.
The vertical ellipsis button opens a window where you can modify the task.
Lastly the x button is supposed to create an event to request cancellation/removal of the selected task.

*Issue lies with creating the events and subscribing to them*. What I have so far are two event handlers which are invoked in each of the buttons click events.

```cs
public event EventHandler<TaskItemEventArgs> TaskCompletedEvent;
public event EventHandler<TaskItemEventArgs> TaskRemoveRequestEvent;

private void acceptBtn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TaskCompletedEvent?.Invoke(this, new TaskItemEventArgs() { EventText = "Task Completed!" });
}

private void removeBtn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TaskRemoveRequestEvent?.Invoke(this, new TaskItemEventArgs() { EventText = "Task Remove Requested!" });
}
```

The problem now is that I don't know where to subscribe these events to in order to modify the "task item" control that invoked the event. I was thinking I should simply add it in the parent control, but I wouldn't know how to go about that, as all the controls here are dynamic.

Now that I think about it, I guess you wouldn't need a control name for the above task. The dynamic controls have me confused though.

Comment: If you are adding the buttons dynamically, makes sense you cant assign the same name.  But you CAN immediately add your click COMMAND binding and command parameter from the code-side for execution so you don't NEED a named element.. Does this make sense?

Comment: @DRapp I guess it makes sense. I'm really new to wpf and it looks like there's a lot of stuff I have to learn to grasp anything here.

Comment: I understand you are learning... I too had similar issue.  But is my assessment accurate?  You are dynamically adding buttons and want them to click and do something for their specific purpose?  If so, what are some examples of the buttons that you are trying to dynamically create and add to the existing task list items control.  Edit your post and put changes at the end instead of a comment that cannot be formatted and is limited length.

Comment: @DRapp I edited the question to add more information.

Comment: Where is `acceptBtn_click` defined? In the control class or in the consuming class?

Comment: @mm8 it's defined in the control class. (TaskListItem). I actually got the code to work now after a bit of experimentation and googling. I dynamically create a stack panel in the TaskList control and when I hit the "plus" button in the top right corner, a dialog opens allowing me to describe my task. After that I dynamically create a TaskListItem and subscribe to it's events with some methods I created in TaskList. Finally I add the TaskListItem to the StackPanel and if I want to modify it I can just modify the specifc object that asked to be edited. Works pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got the code to work now after a bit of experimentation and googling. I dynamically create a stack panel in the TaskList control and when I hit the "plus" button in the top right corner, a dialog opens allowing me to describe my task. After that I dynamically create a TaskListItem and subscribe to it's events with some methods I created in TaskList. Finally I add the TaskListItem to the StackPanel and if I want to modify it I can just modify the specifc object that asked to be edited. Works pretty well.